# Disable pickerInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shinywidgets

I use `pickerInput` from `shinyWidgets` and I would like to disable it. For this purpose, I used the function `disable` form `shinyjs` package but it's doesn't work. But when I use `selectInput` it's work. This is my code :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

##### UI ####

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "somevalue",
    label = "pickerInput",
    choices = c("one", "two")
  ),
  
  br(),
  selectInput(inputId = "test", label = "selectInput",
              choices = c("B", "C")
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

##### SERVER ####
server <- function(session, input, output) { 
  
  shinyjs::disable("somevalue") # doesnt work
  shinyjs::disable("test") # ok it's fine
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can we fix it ?

Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap it in a div and disable that. Note that this is somewhat cosmetic, using the  `shinyjs::disable("somevalue")` will disable it, as no action will be pushed to `server.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

##### UI ####

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(id="somediv",
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "somevalue",
        label = "pickerInput",
        choices = c("one", "two")
      )
  ),
  
  br(),
  selectInput(inputId = "test", label = "selectInput",
              choices = c("B", "C")
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

##### SERVER ####
server <- function(session, input, output) { 
  
  shinyjs::disable("somediv") # ok it's fine
  shinyjs::disable("test") # ok it's fine
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```